# Simple (!?) regex to capture everything between specified pairs of characters

Tags: php, regex

I need to match everything between '**[~**' and '**~]**' tags.

Tried to write a lot of regex patterns but couldn't find correct one:

1. `#\[~(.*)~]#` - this returns everything between first occurrence of **[~** and last occurrence of **~]**.
2. `#\[~([^~]*)~]#` - this works fine if there are no **~** symbol inside tags.

I understand that `(.*)` captures everything and `([^~]*)` captures everything until it finds **~** character but I cant make it to capture everything until it finds **~]** pair (any byte excepting **~]** pair is  possible inside tags including single **~** character). In other words, I dont know how to make negation against the pair of characters.

This is possible example:

```
Simple [example~]: [~here I can face both, ‘~’ and ‘]’ characters~] or another
example [~~~~~~[ABC]~~~~~~].
```

After [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) against regex I expect resulting array like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(44) "here I can face both, '~' and "]" characters"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "~~~~~[ABC]~~~~~"
}
```

**Note:** Input string may contain binary data (00-FF).

Just to mention (for certain people here), I've already checked out all related Q/A + hundreds of Google search results.

Comment: For me it seems to work fine as it is. What do you get, that you don't expect?

Comment: @Svish, first example takes large result or in some cases when I run it against binary content it returns just first occurrence or none. 2nd pattern, as I mentioned above, works fine if there are no ~ symbol inside tags and I understand why. I'm now testing hakre's answer against binary data and I think that ? makes a difference in my pattern, even I still dont know why.

Comment: @Svish, against my example first pattern returns `"here I can face both, ‘~’ and ‘]’ characters~] or another example [~~~~~~[ABC]~~~~~"` and that's obviously not correct. http://www.rubular.com/r/3xFgKN1Psr

Comment: Strange. But making it non-greedy does it fix it, yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is greedy, so it takes as much as it can. You can make it non-greedy (add a `?`) which should solve your issue.

```
#\[~(.*?)~]#
```

The following website has a good description and explains it in more detail: [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

`preg_match` deals with binary strings pretty well, the `.` matches any character which reads as byte if you're in the standard mode (non-utf8) - as you are.

---

Simplified example for explanation:

```
 aab ::  a*  -> aa
```

Matches first an empty string, then a, then aa and then aab does not match so the last match aa is taken and returned. As you can see the engine had first internally three valid matches: empty string, a and aa. The last one wins in greedy-mode.

```
 aab ::  a*? -> (empty string)
```

Is at first position. Needs 0 or more a non-greedy. First position is zero or more a, so matches an empty string and returns. The first one wins in non-greedy-mode.

For UTF-8 strings, use the [`u` modifier (PCRE8)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php): `#.*#u` - `.` matches any UTF-8 character (which can be one or more bytes).

Comment: Seems it works... I tried against normal text, not binary... btw, most of content is UTF-8 encoded. That question mark obviously does a trick. Can you please explain me that **(.*?)** part. It works but I dont know how?

Comment: Yes, it finally works for everything I have tested it against so far (about 30 mixed utf-8 documents w/ some extra binary code in it).